# WordPress edit_user() and Cimy User Extra Fields

Tags: wordpress, updates

I created a page to update a user's WordPress profile. The site uses cimy user extra fields, and adds several custom fields to the users profile. The page gets all of the users data and enters into the appropriate field in the form. Users can make whatever changes they need then click submit.

When the form is posted is calls edit_user(). It returns errors that all of the extra fields are empty. I can echo out the $_POST variables and they are all there. The names match what they are named in the cimy settings panel. The standard WordPress fields are fine. I am not sure if I need to switch to something other than edit_user(), I have looked at a couple of others methods but nothing looks any better than edit_user(), or is there something else I need to do to be able to update the cimy extra fields.

Here is the code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['action'])){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');
    check_admin_referer('update-profile_' . $user_ID);
    $errors = edit_user($user_ID);
    echo $_POST['church'];
    if ( is_wp_error( $errors ) ) {
        foreach( $errors->get_error_messages() as $message )
        $errmsg .= "$message ";
    }
    if($errmsg == ''){
        do_action('personal_options_update', $user_id);
        $d_url = $_POST['dashboard_url'];
        wp_redirect( get_option("siteurl").'?page_id='.$post->ID.'&updated=true' );
    }
    else {
        $errmsg = '<div class="box-red">** ' . $errmsg . ' **</div>';
        $errcolor = 'style="background-color:#FFEBE8;border:1px solid #CC0000;"';
    }
}
```

As per usual, I am sure that I am overlooking something obvious.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The plugin adds cimy_uef_ to the front of the field names. Once I added that everything worked correctly.